# Installing unknown web application on tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I've just downloaded a web application from repository and I want to try it. I only have tomcat installed (no eclipse, idea etc). I don't really know how to start. What I know is directory layout of the code I've just checked out. Is it as simple as dropping it somewhere into tomcat directory structure?

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── README.html
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── META-INF
    │   │   ├── ncbi
    │   │   │   └── blast
    │   │   └── uk
    │   │       └── ac
    │   ├── resources
    │   │   ├── bioactivitiesSql.sql
    │   │   ├── chemblwsclient.properties
    │   │   ├── chemblws.properties
    │   │   ├── log4j.properties
    │   │   ├── schemaFolder
    │   │   │   ├── NCBI_BlastOutput.dtd
    │   │   │   ├── NCBI_BlastOutput.mod.dtd
    │   │   │   └── NCBI_Entity.mod.dtd
    │   │   └── uk
    │   │       └── ac
    │   └── webapp
    │       └── WEB-INF
    │           ├── blast-context.xml
    │           ├── chemblws-client-context.xml
    │           ├── chemblws-servlet.xml
    │           ├── jetty-env.xml
    │           ├── oldOR.xml
    │           ├── override-web.xml
    │           ├── production-override-web.xml
    │           └── web.xml
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── uk
        │       └── ac
        └── resources
            └── log4j.properties
```

Comment: The webapps directory in the tomcat installation is where you need to put the war to deploy it

Comment: To create the war you should have Maven installed on your computer and then execute `mvn package` from your project root directory and it should create a _*.war_ in the target directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Maven-mananged project. Simply do:

```
mvn package
mvn tomcat:run
```

Maven will start an embedded Tomcat with your webapp.